# TypeError when testing/validating read_input (think from return function): python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Very early starter to Python programming and now coming across a bug with what I think is my return functions.

## where I'm at:

Updated the original post after getting some great advice from @Kaushal.

When I'm testing input for "Enter number of patients", I keep getting the following error:

```py
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

I'm thinking it must have to do with my return functions at the top going through and after identifying some wrong input, then makes any input after that 'None'.

Any pointers on how I can fix this bug would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Few pointer to take care of :

1. Use functions, to do repeted work
2. Use exection handling specially in case of reading inputs
3. Use string formating

Note: Used recursion to read the input, uptil no valid input is entered

Below is an implementation of the problem that will help you understand how to implement a problem with functions and error handling in python

**Macro nutrients calculator**

```
def validate_is_positive_numeric(val):
    try:
        val = float(val)
        if val <= 0:
            print("Enter a valid positive value")
            return None, False
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter a valid numeric value")
        return None, False

    return val, True


def read_input(text):
    value, success = validate_is_positive_numeric(input(text))
    if not success:
        value = read_input(text=text)

    return value


def calculate_average(macro_name, total_quantity, total_patients):
    avg = total_quantity/int(total_patients)
    print("Amount of {} (g) required : {}".format(macro_name, avg))


num_patients = read_input("Enter the number of patients: ")


protein, fats, carbs, kilojoules = 0, 0, 0, 0
for _ in range(int(num_patients)):
    protein += read_input("Amount of protein (g) required: ")
    fats += read_input("Amount of fats (g) required: ")
    carbs += read_input("Amount of carbohydrates (g) required: ")
    kilojoules = 4.18*(4*protein + 4*carbs + 9.30*fats)

calculate_average(macro_name="Protein", total_quantity=protein, total_patients=num_patients)
calculate_average(macro_name="Fats", total_quantity=fats, total_patients=num_patients)
calculate_average(macro_name="Carbohydrates", total_quantity=carbs, total_patients=num_patients)
calculate_average(macro_name="Kilojoules", total_quantity=kilojoules, total_patients=num_patients)
```

Comment: Ahhh, awesome. Thanks @Kaushal. That except function is quite powerful, I'll definitely read into those.

Comment: I have now rejigged my code but when testing the execution, I keep getting the following error:
'  File "diet.py", line 27, in <module>
    for i in range(int(number_of_patients)):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable'
'
This is when I test "Enter number of patients" and I put in 'ok', '0' then '1' as the value to get the response. If I put in '1' straight away it works fine. Any idea why that is? :/

Comment: ohh!! got it, we are not accepting the value returned from ```read_input``` during recursion call, hence it was returning the value from the first call made which should be ```None```!! Updated